# Django extension graph_models doesn't generate the characters

Tags: python, django

I ran a Django app on a Docker container, then ssh into it and `pip install pydotplus` and `apk add graphviz`, then I ran `./manage.py graph_models -a -g -o my_project_visualized.png`. It generated a file with model and relationship. But all the characters render as squares, as if they are unicode or something. All my models are English, so should be within ascii range.

django==1.11.23

django-extensions==1.7.7

python==3.7

[image: part of the generated picture]

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by django-extention contributor is install `pango` package. Since this is most likely caused by a missing font.

Instead I copied the file into my local machine and install graphviz locally and convert dot file to svg.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by installing `terminus-font` in the alpine container am using for generation.